# How to install Cockatrice in Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, compiling, github

I'm trying to install the latest client of Cockatrice in Ubuntu. I was told I had to do it from [Github](https://github.com/Cockatrice/Cockatrice), and I'm trying to follow the [instructions](https://github.com/Cockatrice/Cockatrice/wiki/Installing-Cockatrice) but I don't know how to download the Readme file or the other packages, also, I don't really understand what compiling is, I usually just install programs using a .deb file.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 4):

First, clone the Github repository locally to download all the files to your own computer:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Cockatrice/Cockatrice
```

You should then be able to view the README:

```
$ cd Cockatrice
$ less README.md  # or any other plain text file viewer
```

Install the dependencies [like so](https://github.com/Cockatrice/Cockatrice/wiki/Installing-Cockatrice#ubuntu):

```
$ sudo apt-get install libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler qtbase5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev libqt5webkit5-dev libsqlite3-dev qt5-default qttools5-dev-tools qttools5-dev qtmultimedia5-dev libqt5svg5-dev cmake
```

Then follow the instructions in the README for compiling:

```
$ mkdir build   # create directory where complied files will go
$ cd build      # go to that directory
$ cmake ..      # run cmake
$ make          # compile
$ make install  # install
```

Comment: Please note that you will probably also need: `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic git`.

Comment: Sorry for being so noob at this, but it seems I have a problem at the "$ make" step, maybe I'm doing the "cmake" step wrong? Here is a screenshot [link](http://i.imgur.com/Fe8W7o6.png)

Comment: Nevermind! I was missing the ".." after  cmake