# Problem with installing Cockatrice in Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, make

Help. I have error during the make install step.
I follow the instructions in this topic:
[How to install Cockatrice in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605629/how-to-install-cockatrice-in-ubuntu).

Screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: `make install` needs to be run with `sudo` (`sudo make install`) if the target is a system directory such as `/usr/local`

Comment: Please do not post terminal output as screenshot but copy the content (select with mouse, right-click, chose "Copy") and [edit] your question to paste it as text, using code formatting (**`{}`** button or CTRL+K). Also please post English output as most of us do not understand whatever language this is. You make a command run under an English locale by prefixing it with `LANG=C`, i.e. `LANG=C make`. Thanks and welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

`make` can be executed as non-admin user, but `make install` only can be executed as root.

Try with

```
$ sudo make install
```

Good luck.